# How to configure python setuptools to install modules in the root directory as a single package?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am using [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html) to create a python package. This is the directory structure:

```
mypackage
    .git
    __init__.py
    pyproject.toml
    setup.cfg
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

I have this structured in a flat hierarchy so I can clone this repository/copy this directory into a parent project/repository and directly write `from mypackage import something`, instead of having to `pip install` or play around with `PYTHONPATH`.

What do I specify in the `setup.cfg` file, such that this is installed as a single package, given the file structure?

```
# setup.cfg
[options]
package_dir = # What is here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out the [custom discovery options in setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#custom-discovery), which seems to work. I have to manually specify the root directory for packages. However setuptools fails when it finds multiple top-level modules/packages. So I have to use the `find` option to explicitly include discovered modules into a single package.

```
[options]
# Use the find function to find modules/packages
packages = find:
# The root directory is the current directory, relative to setup.cfg
packages_dir =
    .

[options.packages.find]
# Options for the find command. Include is implicitly looking for all .py files,
# where the directory is "."
where = .
```